# Create Conditional Column in a SQL VIEW

Tags: sql-server

I am creating a view from another view in MSSQL.
The Original view has information on a day to day basis of containers filled and their total weight, each row has an Operator_name that indicated who worked on this containers. something like

Operator_name total_containers Total_weight Date

Joe  ....................            10       ..................           1000   ..........         05/01/2020

Joe ....................             25   ..................               2500  ..........          05/02/2020

Carl  ...................           20   ..................               2000...........           05/01/2020

Carl   ...................       30   .................            3000 ...........        05/02/2020

My new view shows for a given Operator the total number of containers and weight he has filled over time, as well as the day average of those values, I also want to add a column that shows the average of containers and weight but just for the last month. I currently have this code

```
SELECT operator_name
    ,SUM(total_container) AS containers
    ,SUM(total_weight) AS weight
    ,AVG(total_container) AS avg_container
    ,AVG(total_weight) AS avg_weight
    ,AVG(weight)
WHERE MONTH(date_time) = MONTH(MAX(date_time)) AS last_weight
FROM dbo.V_TDD_BATCH
GROUP BY operator_name
```

to the Select clause I want to add something like
AVG(total_weight) WHERE MONTH(date_time) = MONTH(MAX(date_time) as last_month_Average/
But of course this syntax is faulty.

Does anyone have an idea how can i create columns like this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: WHERE clause should be after tables info, You cannot give WHERE in select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below Query.

```
WITH lastMonth
AS (
    SELECT operator_name
        ,AVG(total_weight) last_month_Average
    FROM dbo.V_TDD_BATCH
    GROUP BY operator_name
    HAVING MONTH(date_time) = MONTH(MAX(date_time))
    )
SELECT operator_name
    ,SUM(total_container) AS containers
    ,SUM(total_weight) AS weight
    ,AVG(total_container) AS avg_container
    ,AVG(total_weight) AS avg_weight
    ,AVG(weight)
    ,(
        SELECT TOP 1 last_month_Average
        FROM lastMonth
        WHERE operator_name = b.operator_name
        ) AS [last_month_Average]
FROM dbo.V_TDD_BATCH b
GROUP BY b.operator_name
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, when I write your code for the average weight of last month SQL tells me: Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery, this is after I try to save the view

Comment: I'm sorry, trying the other approach.

Comment: @JuanGiraldo Updated the answer, can you check once